# Cardinality of Disjoint Sets, Interval Unions, and Schröder-Bernstein Theorem Clarification

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are non-empty disjoint sets (whether finite or infinite). Can we assert that $|A \cup B| \neq |A|$ and $|A \cup B| \neq |B|$?

Additionally, can we state that $(0, 1)$ and $\{1\}$ are non-empty disjoint sets?

Moreover, is it accurate to claim that $(0, 1) \cup \{1\} = (0, 1]$?

If so, doesn't this imply that $|(0, 1)| \neq |(0, 1]|$, which contradicts the Schröder-Bernstein theorem?

**Edit:**

The aforementioned confusion is in response to the following example in Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications - textbook by Kenneth H. Rosen:

**Question:**
Show that $|(0, 1)| = |(0, 1]|$.

**Solution:**
It may not be immediately apparent how to establish a one-to-one correspondence between $(0, 1)$ and $(0, 1]$ in order to demonstrate that $|(0, 1)| = |(0, 1]|$. Thankfully, we can utilize the Schröder-Bernstein theorem as an alternative approach.

To begin, finding a one-to-one function from $(0, 1)$ to $(0, 1]$ is straightforward. Since $(0, 1) \subset (0, 1]$, the function $f(x) = x$ serves as a clear one-to-one mapping from $(0, 1)$ to $(0, 1]$.

On the other hand, discovering a one-to-one function from $(0, 1]$ to $(0, 1)$ is also not challenging. The function $g(x) = x/2$ is evidently one-to-one and maps $(0, 1]$ to $(0, 1/2] \subset (0, 1)$.

Having successfully identified one-to-one functions from $(0, 1)$ to $(0, 1]$ and from $(0, 1]$ to $(0, 1)$, the Schröder-Bernstein theorem concludes that $|(0, 1)| = |(0, 1]|$.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, we can't.
2. Yes, we can.
3. Yes, it is.
4. Yes, $[(1)\land (2)\land (3)]$ implies $\lvert (0,1)\rvert\ne\lvert(0,1]\rvert$ and the negative of Cantor-Bernstein.

Comment: Given non-empty disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, we have
                                    $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$?

Since $A$ and $B$ are non-empty, $|A \cup B|$(or $|A| + |B|$) is always greater than $|A|$ and $|B|$.
Therefore, $|A \cup B| \neq |A|$ and $|A \cup B| \neq |B|$?

Comment: i) Yes, we do. ii) No, it isn't.

Comment: How so? Why isn't $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| > |A|$(same argument for $|A \cup B| > |B|$) when $A$ and $B$ are non-empty disjoint sets?

Comment: @Spyro2578 For many reasons, among which the one you deliberately refuse to believe.

Comment: Your replies were sadistic and hurtful. If only one would let me know in few words if I am missing something obvious instead of responding with passive-aggresive insults.